# Request to MySQL with sequelize including some relations lasts anomaly long

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js, fastify

Just bumped into this problem, can't figure it out for some days, mb cuz of my lack of knowledge of this technology.

I try to get user data when logging to service with integrated roles system.

So this is the structure of tables, it's pretty simple and abstract:
[image]

And here is the problem, when I try to login to user's account that has a role that has many permissions(more than 50) then the user can get the response after 20-30-40 seconds(all that time takes request of sequelize model actually), but as soon as I remove the big amount of permissions from that role(so remains  up to 10 permissions), request time drops to 1-3 seconds what is totally ok.

This is my sequelize request:

```js
const userData = await this.Model.findByPk(user.id, {
           attributes: { exclude: ['companiesIds'] },
           include: [
               {
                   model: Company,
                   as: 'company',
                   required: true,
                   include: [
                       ... 3 models here...
                   ]
               },
               {
                   model: Company,
                   as: 'companies',
                   attributes: [... attributes ...],
                   through: { attributes: [] }
               },
               {
                   model: Roles,
                   as: 'RoleData',
                   required: false,
                   attributes: ['id', 'name', 'priority'],
                   include: [
                       {
                           model: Permissions,
                           as: 'permissions',
                           attributes: ['id', 'action_name'],
                           through: { attributes: [] }
                       },
                   ]
               }
           ]
       })
```

This is the relations:

```
Roles.belongsToMany(Permissions, { through: RolePermission, as: 'permissions' })
Permissions.belongsToMany(Roles, { through: RolePermission, as: 'roles' })

Roles.hasMany(User);
User.belongsTo(Roles, { foreignKey: 'roleId', as: 'RoleData'});
```

So when I wrap this request with time logs, I can know 20-30-40 seconds pass between logs, so seems like the problem exactly in this request. But can't understand why processing of extra 50 rows takes so long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you indicated several many-to-many associations in the same query. That means that in SQL all these records are multiplied (i.e. if you have 100 records in Companies and 100 in RolePermissions - you'll end up with 10000 records in total in the result SQL dataset). Try to keep only one many-to-many association. It would be better to execute as many queries as many many-to-many associations you want to get along with a user.

Comment: Jesus, that really helps, thank you! Request time dropped to 600ms